# Using Django-Storages with amazon S3 and https

Tags: python, django, python-django-storages

We have an image uploader that uploads to AWS, using django-storages. Right now it sends images over http but we want it to use https.

Googling didn't help me find a way to configure django-storages to do it. Does anyone know the best way to accomplish this, or any documentation that would point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/src/tip/storages/backends/s3.py) it appears you can enable HTTPS by setting `AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = True`.

Comment: is there a clean method to switch it based on requested protocol?

Comment: @digitalPBK 
`from boto.s3.connection import ProtocolIndependentOrdinaryCallingFormat
AWS_S3_CALLING_FORMAT = ProtocolIndependentOrdinaryCallingFormat()`